# How do I override * asterisk for css?

Tags: css, overriding

I am using a JQuery plugin that has this in it's style.css:

```
    * {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

However, for other elements in my css it's causing issues.  For elements where there are issues how can i stop the * from applying that css to certain classes?

Comment: You can change those values for elements you need fixed up by putting them in a separate CSS file (or inline) that is included **after** the plugins CSS file. Ensure that your definitions are more specific (if required). Just ensure that the plugin you're using looks and functions properly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the block.

`*` = Wildcard meaning all div's so will apply this style to all

You should be using a reset style in your CSS to insure browser compatibility so that `margin:0;` & `padding:0;` is trimming any additional `padding &/or margin` that the browser or users' preferences are adding.

If you do not want to delete. Wrap the plugin in a `<div class="jquerypluginwrapper"></div>` then in your CSS:

`.jquerypluginwrapper{ margin:0; padding:0; }` etc.

This means it will not conflict with anything else unless you add the class to another div.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of deleting the block, you could add the class to your div (as meeb0 suggested) and edit your block to read similar to how the plugin was designed.

HTML:

```
<div class="jqueryplugin"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.class, .class  * {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The css above states that the plugin container and everything inside it should inherit the rules stated.